# State Picklists ignoring StyleClass Directive

Tags: visualforce, country-and-state

I'm trying to style my state picklist and it looks like the functionality that allows statecode/countrycode to be dependent on eachother is clobbering the `styleClass` that I specify. When I inspect the page after it loads, there is no class specified on the `select` element.

I think I can clobber it back with jQuery, but is there a better way to do that or is it a known issue?

```
<apex:page showHeader="true" sidebar="true" standardController="Contact">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.MailingStateCode}" styleClass="testClass"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.MailingCountryCode}"/> 
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: From the VF doc on inputField: `The CSS style class used to display the inputField component. This attribute may not work for all values. If your text requires a class name, use a wrapping span tag.`  Key is the `may not work for all values` - try the span with class="testClass".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution for this was:

```
<apex:page showHeader="true" sidebar="true" standardController="Contact">
<script>
var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();

j$(document).ready(function () {
    var obs = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
        mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
            var newNodes = j$(mutation.addedNodes).filter("[id$=stateInput]")
            if(newNodes.length > 0) {
                j$(newNodes[0]).prop('required', true);
                obs.disconnect();
            }
        });
    });
    var config = {attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true};
    obs.observe(j$("#stateDiv span")[0], config);
});

</script>


    <apex:form>
        <div id="stateDiv">
            <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.MailingStateCode}" id="stateInput"/>
        </div>
        <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.MailingCountryCode}"/> 
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Please note that I'm actually adding the "required" attribute, not a class in this solution code. Changing this to add a styleClass would be trivial. The core components of this solution are:

1. An identifiable parent node for the `<apex:inputField>` tag. I used a `<div>` tag.
2. The select tag gets wrapped inside of a `<span>` tag, so we need to select the `<span>` child of the parent `<div>` to watch with our mutationobserver.
3. When a new select tag gets inserted, our callback method can modify it with whatever properties we want.

Comment: Be aware mutationobserver isn't IE10 compliant if you weren't already: http://caniuse.com/#search=mutationobserver

Answer (score 0):

In the [styleClass](https://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_compref_inputField.htm) attribute you need to specify the css ClassName for which you have provided the definition inline or in a css (which you need to include in the page) or simply use the style attribute and provide inline style for example `style="color:red;"` works just fine.

In the below example you can see that `styleClass="italicText"` and the definition of `.italicText` is provided inline.

```
<apex:page>
    <style type="text/css">
        .italicText { font-style: italic; }
    </style>
    <apex:outputText styleClass="italicText" value="This is kind of fancy."/>
</apex:page>
```

You could also refer to a className from a css file which is in the static resources. Check out more examples [here](https://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_styling_custom.htm).

Comment: I understand how to use CSS. Please see crop1645's comment on my question, it covers my issue.

Comment: Thats interesting!  didnt know that would be the rootcause.